# Link and auto-populate attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, relationship-class

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1. I have feature classes in a geodatabase. I am mapping noxious weed patches, and would like to auto-populate the ownership info, mailing address, etc.  The "parcels" feature class contains this info. Parcels may contain more than one patch. Each parcel has a unique "PIN" and I would like to auto-fill by entering the PIN into the patches attribute table.

Is this possible?  What is the correct tool for the job?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is ESRI Attribute Assistant.

http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/

http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-all-methods/#intersecting-feature

http://www.esri.com/esri-news/arcuser/fall-2013/~/media/Files/Pdfs/news/arcuser/1013/attribute.pdf

You will install it, then configure the Dynamic Values table.  You can add custom expressions, or in your case spatial intersections to automatically populate values from the Parcel layer right into your Weed layer.  Ie you drop a point representing weeds in a parcel, attribute assistant will take attributes such as parcel id, address, or your PIN, and automatically populate your weed feature class with those values.
This is a very handy tool and I have used it to do exactly what you are asking about without having to use a spatial join between the two feature classes.

Answer (score 0):

Do a spatial join with your weed patches as the target and your parcel ID as the join attributes. You'll want to join by intersect with a one to one join type.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm